# Kinetic Kame Maturity?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if this has been asked but most of the questions regarding ROS distributions are outdated. I'm thinking about getting into ROS and most sources recommend indigo because packages are plentiful. The thing is, those were before lunar released so is kinetic old enough to have good package support or should I stick with indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269005/kinetic-kame-maturity?/) by [StormFalcon32](https://answers.ros.org/users/31597/stormfalcon32/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
I would say that Kinetic has pretty good support. I use both Indigo and Kinetic daily and have found that many (most) of the packages that work with Indigo work with Kinetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current recommendation is to use Kinetic. See also [wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions).

There will still be a difference in the nr of packages supported by both Indigo and Kinetic, but that is something that is true of all ROS distributions (ie: Hydro and Indigo showed a similar difference).

And as @jayess hints at: if you need something that is not available on Kinetic, chances are high that building from source in a Catkin workspace -- which you will need to create for your own work anyway -- will work, as the differences between Kinetic and Indigo are relatively minor for a lot of things. The [wiki/kinetic/Migration](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration) page has info on that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2